# SQL Server 2008 Trigger: Checking value in the inserted

Tags: sql, triggers, constraints

I am studying trigger to compare values (trigger is hard lol)

I am getting trouble to check id which should be inside of `inserted`

For example, let's say we have table `testTb1` with data rows:

```
|id|section_id|current_num_student|max_num_student|
|1 |1         | 23                | 23            |
|2 |3         | 21                | 29            |
|3 |5         | 50                | 50            |
```

`current_num_student` is the number of student in the class and `max_num_student` is maximum in the class. `max_num_student` will be defined by teacher, so it could be any numbers.

Now a student wants to add the section 5, however `current_num_student` is equal to `max_num_student`. Therefore, we have to reject a student.

Query in the jsp file is like..

```
update testTb1  
SET current_num_student = current_num_student + 1 
WHERE section_id = ?
```

"?" will be input data by user in jsp.

Therefore, I was trying to make trigger such as..

```
ALTER TRIGGER testTrg
on dbo.testTb1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
 if EXISTS(select * FROM inserted FULL JOIN dbo.testTb1 m ON 
 m.section_id = inserted.section_id AND m.num_cur = m.num_max)
Begin
 RAISERROR ('Can not update data because class is full', 16,1);
rollback tran
END
```

When I manually using query to test first, case that returning error message

```
UPDATE mydata.dbo.testTb1 
SET num_cur =  num_cur + 1 
WHERE section_id = 1
```

I am getting message such as

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure testTrg, Line 9
>   Can not update data because class is full
>   Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

However, when I was trying

```
UPDATE mydata.dbo.testTb1 
SET num_cur =  num_cur + 1 
WHERE section_id =3
```

which must be **NO ERROR** case (must be increasing `current_num_student` )

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure testTrg, Line 9
>   Can not update data because class is full
>   Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Therefore, I am guessing that `inserted.section_id` doesn't contain any value.

However, I am not really sure my guessing is correct or not.

If my trigger syntax wrong, can you tell me the part that I need to fix ?

or

if trigger syntax is correct, can you tell me the way to print the value of `inserted.section`

Comment: This is your *third* question on this - what's wrong with the previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

your second update query is using other database name, shouldn't it be `mydata`

```
  UPDATE **cse132b**.dbo.testTb1 
  SET num_cur =  num_cur + 1 
  WHERE section_id =3
```

Comment: sorry, my bad i just changed lol . it was mydata.dbo.testTb1 SET num_cur = num_cur + 1 WHERE section_id =3

Answer (score 0):

It is [full join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx) giving you a headache.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for a `FULL JOIN`, which is synonymous with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. This will return all rows from `inserted`, and all rows from `testTbl1`. *If* those rows match your join condition, they'll be joined. Otherwise, nulls will appear in all columns on the unjoined side.

I think you want an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    CREATE TABLE testTb1(
            id      INT,
            section_id      INT,
            current_num_student     INT,
            max_num_student INT
    )
    INSERT INTO testTb1(id, section_id, current_num_student, max_num_student) VALUES
    (1, 1, 23, 23),
    (2, 3, 21, 29),
    (3, 5, 50, 50)

    ;CREATE TRIGGER dbo.testTrg
    on dbo.testTb1
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    if EXISTS(select 1 
              FROM inserted 
                   INNER JOIN dbo.testTb1 m ON 
                        inserted.section_id = m.section_id
              WHERE inserted.current_num_student >= inserted.max_num_student)
    Begin
            RAISERROR ('Can not update data because class is full', 16, 1);
            rollback tran
    END

    select * from testTb1

    UPDATE testTb1
    SET current_num_student = current_num_student + 1
    WHERE Id = 1
```